# Sequelize: belongsToMany and cascade deleting

Tags: javascript, mysql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Good day. I have 3 tables:

1. People: id, name
2. Places: id, name
3. PeoplePlaces: id, person_id, place_id

And i have models for this tables:

```
function Person(Sequelize, sequelize) {
  return sequelize.define('people', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    birthdate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
      timestamps: false
  });
}
```

---

```
function Place(Sequelize, sequelize) {
  return sequelize.define('places', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
      timestamps: false
  });
}
```

---

```
function PersonPlace(Sequelize, sequelize) {
  return sequelize.define('peopleplaces', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
      timestamps: false
  });
}
```

So, e.g. i want to delete person with id = 1:

```
sequelize.people.destroy({ where: { personId: pId } })
```

But i have an error on deleting, that says to me that table `PersonPlaces` contains FK to Person and it cannot be deleted.

I try to use `onDelete: 'cascade'`: `People.belongsToMany(Places, { through: PeoplePlaces, onDelete: 'cascade' });`

But without good result.

So, how i can delete one person from `People` that have FK on it from `PeoplePlaces`?

Comment: Do you use migrations to synchronise the database or `sequelize.sync()` method?

Comment: @piotrbienias no, i didn't use it

Comment: I asked if you use migrations or `sync` and you said no... Which one do you use to synchronise the database?

Comment: @piotrbienias i'm not use one of them. But i'm added it and now all works fine, code first awesome, thank you!

Comment: I face the same problem. @Evgeniy175 how did you fix it?